# JFileChooser getCurrentDirectory() to String

Tags: java, string, swing, filenames, jfilechooser

I have this code:

```
JFileChooser openFolder = new JFileChooser();
openFolder.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
openFolder.setDialogTitle("Select target directory");
openFolder.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
openFolder.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
if (openFolder.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{      
    File newLoc = openFolder.getCurrentDirectory();   
}
```

How can I make it so that It converts this:

```
    File newLoc = openFolder.getCurrentDirectory();
```

To a String if its possible?

For example using the FileChooser I chose the folder: C:\Music

I tried using:

```
String locToString = FileUtils.readFileToString(newLoc);
```

but it doesn't work.

I want to convert it to string so I can make it appear on a JTextField using:

```
jTextField.setText(locToString);
```

Comment: Every Object has a toString() method. Just invoke the `toString()` method on your `File` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newLoc.getAbsolutePath() will give you a String from a File, per the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: It says wait 2 minutes

Comment: SO best practices say you should also vote up answers that help